# Нужно ли уметь использовать Promise ReactJS разработчику?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, асинхронность, promise

Я ещё обучаюсь ReactJS'у и когда я смотрел гайд, человек затронул Promise и сказал, что это очень полезная часть разработки на JavaScript, но я вообще впервые слышу про них и уже сделал проект на React'е без них, в колледже больше года работали на JavaScript и вообще ни разу никто не упомянул Promise, вопрос для знающих фронтовиков, желательно на ReactJS, нужно ли джуну ReactJS знать, как работать с Promise? Я немного совсем почитал про синхронные и асинхронные функции, пока вообще не понимаю что это и почему я не столкнулся с этим за довольно продолжительное обучение.

Comment: _«нужно ли джуну ReactJS знать, как работать с Promise?»_ - обязательно (и без реакта тоже). От джуна вообще ожидается полное знание используемого языка программирования и сопутствующих вещей (в вебе это DOM и техн. стек выбранной специализации)... младшим программистам необязательны только навыки проектирования и управления, а вот в инструментарии от них ожидается компетенция (т.к. в задачи джуна входит реализация уже готовых решений от старших коллег). Конечно, в разных местах разное понимание ранжирования и разные требования, это я усреднил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В разработке клиентской части приходится делать сложные вычислительные операции или запросы к серверу. Эти операции могут выполняться какое время, если делать их синхронно, то будет блокировка интерфейса браузера (то есть как будто страница зависала), на помощь приходят асинхронные функции в javascript. А промисы это просто удобная обертка для работы с асинхронными операциями.

```
const myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    // код который нужно выполнить ассинхронно
});
myFirstPromise
.then((successMsg) => {
    // успешно выполненная операция
    console.log(successMsg);
})
.catch((errorMsg) => { 
    // ошибка при выполненнии операция
    console.log(errorMsg);
});
```

а вот подобный код без использование промисов:

```
  async function myFirstPromise() {
    try {
    // успешно выполненная операция
    } catch (error) {
    // ошибка при выполненнии операция
    console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

[Подробнее можно почитать тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, получается, что при обороте fetch .then я использовал промисы, просто не знал, что это они и есть?

Comment: да, fetch как раз возвращает Promise